# Load bulk products through CSV file import/export

Tags: php, magento, csv, export-to-csv

I was asked to build a Magento website by one of my clients.Then all of a sudden he asked whether I can load bulk products through CSV file import/export, etc.
But I have a little knowledge in this thing.In fact my knowledge in this is very poor.So can you please explain this?I searched in the internet and read some articles but I couldn't get a proper idea.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the default Import/Export fit for you?

`Magento Admin > System > Import/Export > Profiles`

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/export_tool